# On my WAMP, Apache will not start when I set it to log in as a user but will otherwise

Tags: apache, wamp, windows-server-2003

I am unable to start Apache when I try to log it in as the local user on my computer (windows server 2003). It starts just fine if I set it to be the local system account.

Any ideas on what could be preventing it?

Comment: permissions, most likely. check the windows event log to see if it records why it's failing.

Comment: The Apache2.2 service terminated with service-specific error 1 (0x1).
is what the log says

Comment: start>run>cmd 
go to c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache XXX/bin/  
httpd.exe -S
It should end with "syntax OK" otherwise it will through error,
with me, some syntax error in httpd.conf, After fixing syntax error. Server got started.